# Using Durable Services for saving wcf instances

Tags: wcf, web-services, durable-services

I am currently creating a service which connects to a DAL and that can run a few stored procedures, one of the issues I am facing is that for certain times of the month, we can't update the database, (at the moment this is done manually. This is done via the user adding a note to their calendar)

But I would like to automate this process, one of the possible solutions I can think of using is a durable service. When the date is lets say the 1st of the month, the Update/Insert/Delete instances can get saved to a database, and then ran after that date in a batch.

Is this the intended use of durable services ?
Is there a better route I could possibly take ?

Comment: Thanks, I just discovered durable services yesterday, so I was wondering if they could be applied to my solution. Will now look into queuing thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not really what durable services are for. Durable services are really for keeping persisted state relating to instances of the service between invocations (i.e. continuations).

It seems to me like in your situation, a better option would be to have the service write the operation into a queue and then have something else (i.e. another service, or the same service with a different binding) get that stuff from the queue and process it at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

A WCF durable service is a service in which the state is maintained during the different calls. Using Context enabled bindings you can create WCF Durable Services. Please visit below link for more information.

[context enabled bindings and durable services](http://ultimatetutorial.com/post/wcf-context-enabled-bindings)